# How can I apply this Vs(t) = 5cos(2000t) into the multisim circuit?

Tags: multisim

I found the rms =  3.53

it has 2000t whereas omega,w = 2000

so how can I use it to the AC source

[image]

Comment: Are you just asking how to convert the value of 2000 in the expression to a frequency in Hertz? Or is there a different question?

Answer (score 0):

I assume an AC voltage source in Multisim produces a signal something like:

$$ v(t) = B + A_{PK} \cdot sin (2\pi ft - 2\pi\frac{\phi}{360}) $$

Where:

- \$B\$ is the offset, in volts. This corresponds to the "Voltage offset" field. There is no offset term in your expression, so it should remain 0.
- \$A_{PK}\$ is peak voltage. The "Voltage (RMS)" field will be:
  $$ A_{RMS} = \frac{A_{PK}}{\sqrt 2} = \frac{5}{\sqrt 2} = 3.54V $$
- \$f\$ is frequency, in hertz, which is entered in the "Frequency (F)" field. In your expression, frequency \$\omega\$ is in \$\frac{rad}{s}\$, which needs to be converted to hertz using the relationship \$\omega = 2 \pi f\$:
  $$ f = \frac{\omega}{2\pi} = \frac{2000}{2\pi} = 318 Hz $$
- \$\phi\$ is phase *lag*, in degrees. That's the "Phase" field. Given that cosine is simply sine, with a *lead* of 90°, set the "Phase" field to \$\phi=-90°\$. It's possible that Multisim treats this value as phase lead (I am not familiar with Multisim), in which case you must change the sign, to \$\phi=+90°\$.